# Groovy json string empty

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am working with SoapUI and are really new to this. I am supposed to make a few REST tests, a lot of them have to do with dynamic resources so I have to read some json results on runtime. This works fine the first time I do it:

```
    ...
    def response = context.expand('${Get ContractModels#Response}')
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)


    for (i in slurper.ContractModels){
        testRunner.testCase.testSteps["ContractModelOptionStep"].setPropertyValue("id",sprintf('%d',i.ContractModelID));
        testRunner.runTestStepByName("ContractModelOptionStep")       

        def innerResponse = context.expand('${Get ContractModelOptionStep#Response}')
        log.info(response)
        log.info(innerResponse)
        def innerSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(innerResponse);
        ...
    }
```

This works well up to the last line, where it tells me The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty. Thanks to the log.info I found out the JSON Strong of innerResponse is actually empty. Now my problem is I have no clue why, runTestStepByName works perfectly fine and gives the expected response.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two lines:

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName("ContractModelOptionStep")

def innerResponse = context.expand('${Get ContractModelOptionStep#Response}')
```

the name of the test step does not match! Try:

```
def innerResponse = context.expand('${ContractModelOptionStep#Response}')
```

Comment: Wow...that's emberassing embarrassing from my side, thank you.